# building pylibmc with sasl support

Tags: python, memcached, libmemcache

I'm trying to build the latest version of pylibmc (1.2.2) to support SASL on CentOS 6.  The documentation says that the build require libsasl2, which I have in /usr/lib64/, however, the build process for the python package does not seem to recognize the library is there.

I build the package with:
python setup.py install --with-libmemcached=/usr/local/lib --with-zlib --with-sasl2

Then run the tests:
python runtests.py

```
nose.plugins.pylibmc: INFO: injected path: build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6
nose.plugins.pylibmc: INFO: loaded _pylibmc from build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/_pylibmc.so
nose.plugins.pylibmc: INFO: libmemcached version: 0.51
nose.plugins.pylibmc: INFO: pylibmc version: 1.2.2
nose.plugins.pylibmc: INFO: support compression: True
nose.plugins.pylibmc: INFO: support sasl auth: False
....................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 20 tests in 4.839s

OK
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pylibmc uses libmemcached, so for support saml you should rebuild libmemcached with saml, for that you need to install saml libries, then rebuild libmemcached from source code.